# What are the effects of directly importing a .css file into a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, css

I have found this index.js, on the root level of a React project.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The index.css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Publico-medium";
    src: url('./assets/fonts/publico-medium.woff') format('woff');
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto-bold";
    src: url('./assets/fonts/roboto-bold.woff') format('woff');
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto-medium";
    src: url('./assets/fonts/roboto-medium.woff') format('woff');
  }
  
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    src: url('./assets/fonts/roboto-normal.woff') format('woff');
  }
```

What are the effects of this import?

Comment: Have a read through this: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the React docs:

`In development, expressing dependencies this way allows your styles to be reloaded on the fly as you edit them. In production, all CSS files will be concatenated into a single minified .css file in the build output.`

Reference: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-stylesheet/

Comment: So in my case, since I am not creating css classes in my stylesheet, I am resetting the body properties app-wide?